# What makes different permission request position in code change android app behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an Android app that downloads data from Firestore using different `object` classes and needs user position access permission.
I have a function in `object FirestoreDowloader` class that is resposible of downloading from Firestore:

```
fun getCollection(
        collectionPath: Collections,
        checkSignature: Boolean = true,
        onCompletion: (ArrayList<Map<String, Any>>, ReadingError?) -> (Unit)
    ) {

        val result = ArrayList<Map<String, Any>>()
        if (DeviceManager.isConnected()) {

            val collectionReference = db.collection("/" + collectionPath.value)
            val query = if (checkSignature)
                collectionReference.whereEqualTo(signatureField, signature)
            else
                collectionReference

            query.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->

                    //do stuff
                    onCompletion(result, null)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    onCompletion(
                        ArrayList(),
                        ReadingError.NOT_AUTHENTICATED
                    )
                }
        } else
            onCompletion(ArrayList(), ReadingError.DISCONNECTED)
    }
```

that is called by three different `object` classes.
One of them downloads a list of elements to be displayed in a `RecyclerView`
Before adding the position permission request the app worked pretty well, but now I am facing different problems:

1. the `onCompletion` lamdba is apparently not called, hence the app can't store what is downloaded
2. if I don't grant the position permission the app doesn't show the downloaded list in the `RecyclerView`
3. If I grant the position permission the app shows the downloaded list, but if I go to settings to revoke the permission in my phone without closing the app and then reopen it, I see an empty  `RecyclerView`.

I found a temporary solution so far: if I place the request permission at the end of all downloads the app works fine, but I this can't be the final solution because the app should work regardlessly of the the request permission position.

Can that be caused by some thread conflicts?